# How to get page title in Nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am struggling to find a way to get page title in Nuxt 3 and reuse it in layout. I am pretty sure there is a way to do it through some meta object but I just can not find it.

I tried to do it through route meta

*/layouts/default.vue*

```js
<template>
    <h1>
        {{ route.meta.title }}
    </h1>
</template>

<script setup>
    const route = useRoute();
</script>
```

But now when I have to set title I need to do it twice so this method works

*/pages/catalog.vue*

```js
<script setup>
    definePageMeta({
        title: 'Catalog Page',
    });

    useHead({
        title: 'Catalog Page',
    });
</script>
```

Seems realy hacky so I open to ideas here

Comment: Share you idea, so we can work with it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You might be interested in [Layout](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts)

Comment: The object that `definePageMeta` takes, does not allow `title`.

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/define-page-meta#type

Also, I think the answer to the question is no, there is no reliable way.

Comment: @LeopoldKristjansson It is possible to augment the type of the object accepted by `definePageMeta` https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#typing-custom-metadata

Comment: @LeopoldKristjansson I don't get what you want to express. I would just like to correct your first phrase as `definePageMeta` can include any meta besides what have already defined in type and users can also augment this type to have intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

The question's author is correct, though it's not required to use both. If anything, that's a problem specific to their project.

Using `definePageMeta` is the recommended approach, as per the Nuxt [SEO and Meta](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/seo-meta#examples) documentation.

On each of your page components:

```js
// ~/pages/Dashboard.vue

<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  title: 'Dashboard'
})
</script>
```

You can then access the title in another component, like a common navigation menu:

```js
// ~/components/Menu.vue

<script setup>
const route = useRoute()
</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ route.meta.title }}</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

`useHead()` allows you to edit site/page title - https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-head

```js
<script setup>
useHead({
  title: "My custom page title"
})
</script>
```

It can also be a dynamic, even reactive value.

Just not sure what you mean with "getting" it?

For example in my [Nuxt demo project](https://github.com/AloisSeckar/demos-nuxt/tree/main/nuxt-stack) I defined page title inside `app.config.ts` [file](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/app-config):

```js
export default defineAppConfig({
  textTitle: 'Nuxt Demos - Nuxt Stack'
})
```

and then I reference it via `useHead` in `app.vue`:

```js
useHead({
  title: useAppConfig().textTitle
})
```

Might this help you?

Comment: `useAppConfig().textTitle` is probably what OP mean aka accessing the title of the page. In opposition to a setter where you edit it.

Comment: Different pages can have different titles so using predefined textTitle is not an option.

Comment: You can use whatever JS expression you like instead of `useAppConfig().textTitle`. Might be a constant for each page or a result of a function with current page as an attribute. This might be either hard-coded, or you may use `useRoute().path` or `useRoute().fullPath` to get current URL.

Comment: I get a translation for page from an API, so getting it from url is not working

Comment: And how do you get it? `useHead({ title: <<api call result>> })` not possible?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the current title and rework it somehow you can always use

```
document.title
```

as long as it is not server-side rendered

Comment: Nuxt is mainly used on the server + has reactive values tho, no need to use vanilla JS.

Comment: For SEO reasons it would be more preferable to render title on server so this one does not help

Answer (score -1):

I use i18n, on my component, I do code bellow, It worked for me

```
{{ $t(`${$route.meta.title}`) }}
```